# insert a map<String,Object> in mongodb with java

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, json

I'm trying to insert a map in mongodb ( in java), but I d'ont know what's the best way to do it.
I translated the contents of an XML file in jsonObject and I put it in a map : XML=>JsonObject JsonObject=>map, now i want to store it in mongodb.
here is the code that store the map in mongodb :

```
                 Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost",27017);
                 DB db = mongo.getDB("mydb");
                 //get a single collection 
                 DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("test");

                 //convert JSON to DBObject directly 
                  collection.insert(new BasicDBObject(map));
                 DBCursor cursorDoMap = collection.find();
                  while (cursorDoMap.hasNext()){
                      System.out.println(cursorDoMap.next());

                  }

                inputStream.close();
                 mongo.close();}

                catch (UnknownHostException e)
                  {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                catch (MongoException e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
  }
```

but when I run it I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
```

Comment: mongodb documents are actually bson which is a binary representation of json. Therefore why don't you insert json object?

Comment: I thought i had to convert the json into a map to store it in mongodb and it's easy to manipulate the object with the map.

Comment: A json object is a document for mongo. You can manipulate with your object and then store it. Take a look at mongodb's own website for inserting. https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/insert/

Comment: thank you for your reply, so I can insert it directly without going through a map?

Comment: Yes sure, you can. Just try it

Comment: I tried to store the map but i get this error message : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes